# How is that possible to be $X$ discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Suppose that the cumulative distribution function of discreate random variable $X$ is given by,
> $$F(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0  & \text{$x$ < 0 } \\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{x}{4} & \text{$0 \leq x<1$}\\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x-1}{4} & \text{$1 \leq x<2$}\\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{11}{12}   &\text{$2 \leq x<3$}\\[1.5ex]
> 1 &\text{$3 \leq x$}\\
> \end{cases}$$
> Find $P(X=i),i=1,2,3$.

My problem is, how is that possible to be $X$ discrete random variable as I think it is mixed random variable(both discrete and continuous) since there are $x$ in $F(X)$. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is neither discrete nor continuous.  $P(X=1)=\frac 12  -\frac1  4=\frac  1 4$ (the jump at $x=1$) etc.

For any random variable $X$ we have $P(X=x)=F_X(x)-F_X(x-)$ where $F_X(x-)$ is the left hand limit of $F_X$ at $x$. In this case the right hand limit of $F$ at $1$ is $\frac 1  2$ and the left hand limit is $\frac  1 4$ so the difference is $\frac 1 4$.

Comment: Can you elaborate it with more details?

Comment: @puka I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

Well answered by Kavi sir.
Let's see it visually.

You can see from graph its neither discrete nor continuous it's mixed of both.

[image]

Let's zoom a little bit and look at the required probabilities.

[image]